# LogAnalyticsReader unable to access AzRecoveryServicesBackupStatus

Tags: azure

I'm writing a Powershell script that queries the status of the latest backup of VMs as follows:

```
$recoveryVaultInfo = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupStatus -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Type 'AzureVM'
```

When I run this piece of the script, I get this error:

> Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupStatus: The client 'XXX' with object id
> 'XXX' does not have authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/locations/backupStatus/action' over scope
> '/subscriptions/XXX' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently
> granted, please refresh your credentials.

I am a member of the LogAnalyticsReader group on the BackupVault. I am able to see the status of backups through the Backup Vault > Backup Items blade.

Why can't I do it through Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Backup reports can be viewed as long as their data is being sent to a Log Analytics workspace. To view reports for a vault or a set of vaults, you need to have reader access to the **Log Analytics workspace** to which the vault is sending its data. You don't have to have access to the vault.